# Software to help with recording vinyl albums to CD

Tags: windows, music, audio-recording

I currently use [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) to record my old vinyl albums onto my media centre. However, the process of splitting the album up into named and tagged tracks is tedious in the extreme.

Give the presence of technology like [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/), [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/), etc., which can recognise music, and return the album, artist, track names and lengths automatically, I don't understand why I can't find software (for Windows) which records the input from the sound card, fingerprints it, looks it up on the Internet music databases, decides which album it is from, works out when each track starts (from the information in the music database, and perhaps analysing the silences to make sure everything is lined up), and then saves everything as separately named and tagged tracks.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or is there some other problem preventing the development of such software?